# Does Spring Data JPA have any way to sum an entity column using method name resolving?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA can sum colomn using specifications. But does it have any way to sum an entity column using method name resolving? Let's say I want a method sumCreditAmount to sum column with specific name, just like a method findByCreditAmount to fetch all entities with a specific creditAmount.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spring Data JPA does not provide inbuilt support for aggregate methods. But you can get sum by using:

```
@Query("SELECT sum(e.creditAmount) from Entity e")
int sumCreditAmount();
```

You need to declare the above method in your repository class.